# Powershell 7 - Parallel While Loops

Tags: powershell, while-loop

I'm running PowerShell 7 and since workflows are no longer supported, I'm running into an issue with parallel while loops. Keeping the example below simple, I just need to run both while's in parallel in the same script but need to ensure that the sleep command works as well within the while loop.

I can't figure a good way of doing this with foreach-object and doing background jobs with while loops - the sleep command never activates driving up CPU. Should be simple but not finding much out there. Again, below is just a simple example of what I need to run.

```
while ($true) 
{
    write-host "Doing first task"
    Start-Sleep 2
}


while ($true)
{
    write-host "Doing second task"
    Start-Sleep 2
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't pass an array of scriptblocks to foreach-object, so here's a start-threadjob version, which is similar.

I think you mean to have a semicolon before start-sleep to start a new statement.

```
start-threadjob { while ($true) { 
  write-host Doing first task; Start-Sleep 2 } }
start-threadjob { while ($true) { 
  write-host Doing second task; Start-Sleep 2 } }
get-job | receive-job -wait -autoremovejob


Doing first task
Doing second task 
Doing first task 
Doing second task 
Doing first task 
Doing second task 
# ...
```

Ah, here's a way.  And the output order varies randomly.

The two tasks could also be scripts, but not functions.

```
1,2 | foreach-object -parallel {
  switch ($_) {
    1 { while ($true) { write-host Doing first task; Start-Sleep 2 } }
    2 { while ($true) { write-host Doing second task; Start-Sleep 2 } }
  }
}


Doing first task
Doing second task
Doing second task
Doing first task
Doing second task
Doing first task
# ...
```